# Powershell To Read From Network Location

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to access a DLNA server that is set-up by using the dir structure created by clicking through it from My Computer, like the below
[image: Serviio] [image: Dir Structure]

Now I want to read the file names in the folder and write them.  This is the syntax I have tried

```
Get-ChildItem "This PC\Serviio (AMDDesktop)\Video\Folders\TV Shows\Battlebots\Season 01"
Foreach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName
    Write-Host $content
}
```

But it produces an error that says the path does not exist.
[image: Full error message]

What would be the proper way to iterate these files?  Or better yet, maybe the proper way to word the ? is how do I get the address to these files to iterate?

Comment: The proper way would be to use the proper path :). The path that is shown in windows explorer is without drive information, slashes, ... . It's a pretty print version if you will. You should click on any whitespace in the toolbar to show the *real* path *(or <ALT+D>)* and use that.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers AFAIK, DLNA paths are not ordinary paths but point to the media server. Thus accessing is not just a whitespace issue.

Comment: @vonPryz - Totally missed that part, you are probably right.

Comment: Wow, thank you for that valuable insight!  Would accessing via IP address then folder structure work?  Or would I need to use hostname?

Comment: Can you post the path Windows Explorer shows? I know next to nothing about DLNA but it might be possible to add a share on that server so you can access it through SMB.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - you mean this path? `This PC\Serviio (AMDDesktop)\Video\Folders\TV Shows\Battlebots\Season 01`